# Gap between the removed thingadongdong and the user-information bar at the top of the page

Tags: bug, status-completed

Replicated by @YiJiang on FX4, and by me and @TimStone on Chrome (stable and dev respectively)

[image: shows the issue at hand]

notice I'm not showing as logged in either, but that may or may not be related. Notice that when I was logged in, it showed that I had obtained the autobio badge, and when I cleared that, the page did the expected thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been fixed in the code, just waiting for a regularly scheduled publish.