# There's a gap between the topbar and the you-need-JS div

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

*There's a gap between the topbar and the you-need-JS `<div>`

It happens to me even if I have the login priv

Don't get me wrong, I think the new topbar's a work of art

But this is buggy CSS, and should be fixed quick-smart!*

---

More seriously (and less poetically), observe:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

<sup>See also [Gap between the removed thingadongdong and the user-information bar at the top of the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93946/gap-between-the-removed-thingadongdong-and-the-user-information-bar-at-the-top-o), which is a similar problem claiming to be fixed.</sup>

Comment: Like with askubuntu.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I believe the askubuntu gap is by design to separate Canonical's top bar from ours. Not 100% sure off-hand, though.

Comment: I mean the gap between the canonical top bar and the "Give me JS PLZ." bar.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Ah, sorry. I misunderstood.

Comment: OK, so there is a gap. And what about it? Why do you think it's a bug and not aesthetic decision?

Comment: @Mołot My sense of UI taste says this was not an aesthetic decision.

Comment: +1 since it's a valid and good report and I'm glad you made it. If it's deliberately that way, someone can come in and tell us as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This most egregious error of design shall be fixed in the next build.  Unfortunately it was also the last strike - we'll have to summarily execute our designer at noon.  Apologies for future design bugs taking longer to fix, but rules are rules.